# How to display a selected simple product's image for configurables in the catalog?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3.4, simple-product

We import configurables without images, but the simples have images (marked by a special attribute).

How can we show the image of a simples as main image of the configurables (thumbnail, base image)

*EDIT*

There seems to be already similar logic in the core:

`\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::setImageFromChildProduct`

```
public function setImageFromChildProduct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    if (!$product->getData('image') || $product->getData('image') === 'no_selection') {
        foreach ($this->getUsedProducts($product) as $childProduct) {
            if ($childProduct->getData('image') && $childProduct->getData('image') !== 'no_selection') {
                $product->setImage($childProduct->getData('image'));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return parent::setImageFromChildProduct($product);
}
```

Problem is that I need something similar for category (product list) pages and I think they [do not use the image but the small image](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/magento/magento-images/).

Comment: what does mesn marked by a special attribute?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy I created a image attribute, main_config_image which I add the images to in the simple product. This images I want to show in the configurable product which have those simples as a child product

Comment: Just Like any other image, for example small_image. My main problem is how to get the simple product's images when displaying the configurable

Comment: sorry, too much is unknown, I could see myself spending a good amount of time and yet not resolving your problem as I can't be 100% sure I use the same data as you, good luck